# Redux form cannot type

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I cannot type in the text input of redux form. 
it's a very minimal form

```
function Login({ handleSubmit, handleChange }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(undefined);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(undefined);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);
  };

  console.log(handleSubmit);
  return (
    <Container>
      <div className={styles.centered}>
        <div className={styles.form}>
          <div className={styles.title}>
            <H3>Login</H3>
          </div>
          <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={styles.flexColumn}>

            <div className={styles.username}>
              <P>username</P>
              <Field name="username" component="input" type="text" className={styles.input} />
            </div>

            <div className={styles.password}>
              <P>password</P>
              <Field name="password" component="input" type="password" className={styles.input} />
            </div>

            <div className={styles.downSection}>
              <Flex>
                <P>
                Serve Aiuto?
                </P>
                <a href="#">
                  <div className={styles.contactLink}>
                    <P>Contattaci</P>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </Flex>
              <Button type="submit" text="Accedi" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  login: loginAction,
};

const enhance = compose(
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),
  reduxForm({ form: 'login' }),
);

export default enhance(Login);
```

The handleSubmit doesn't work, i cannot console.log anything. 
I tried to see the documentation and tried to search some answer on SO but i didn't find an answer.

Could you please tell me where is the error ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several hours and a special night of bug fixing i discovered the problem:

it was in one import, exactly:

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
```

and not

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
```

this was completely unexpected, i was pretty sure that the mistake was in the body of the component, not in the import.

the structure of the file was ok.

Answer (score 1):

So give this a try, let's leave `enhance` out, I don't know what it does honestly so let's try this type of Login configuration where we turn the component into a class-based one which is good practice anyway since you are receiving inputs from a user.

I do realize you are using `useState` which is some of the cool new features with React, but what I am recommending is to put together a less complex and conventional setup with a class-based component like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <label>Email</label>
          <Field
            name="email"
            type="text"
            component="input"
        
          />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label>Password</label>
          <Field
            name="password"
            type="password"
            component="input"

          />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: "login" })(Login);
```

Use this to check to see if you can now type into your inputs and then start adding stuff back in and test it every single time until you find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try first just to handle the event

```
 <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={styles.flexColumn}>
```

after that try using the this in the function onsubmit and remove the const

```
 onSubmit(event){
console.log(e);
console.log(username);
console.log(password);
   this.handleSubmit(event.target.value);
  };
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help: if i try to launch only onSubmit i can see the console.log inside of it ( with undefined value ). 

But i'm not able to type anything in the text input